# Is there a way in Springboot to do the internationalization with dynamic data with out using property files

Tags: java, spring-boot

Generally, for internationalisation, we use .properties files to get the en/es/fr data.

Because for my specific use case, the content of the dictionary is not static, but dynamically changed at runtime, I am wondering if there is an API in Spring Boot, to implement this requirement.

Comment: Are you sure that you need dynamic values to internationalize. Can't you change the attributes?

Comment: Spring uses MessageSource, has several implementations, and you're free to create a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and because i want dynamic i18n message. I decided to store my message in database and via `Spring localeResolver` bean get local and request database to get related message. So I can add message to database in runtime , in multiple language.

You can refer to this :https://vkuzel.com/spring-boot-internationalisation-with-database-stored-messages-and-ibm-icu